# Chef Server 12 on Debian Jessy fails with "unable to change to service directory"

Tags: chef, runit, chef-server

While not being officially supported, I want to run Chef Server 12 (12.3.0) on Debian Jessie.

After fixing Debian's systemd ego trip as described in [chef-cookbooks/chef-server#86](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-server/issues/86#issuecomment-151930819), it is installing and running successfully.

However, the `runit` setup seems not correct:

```
# chef-server-ctl status
fail: bookshelf: unable to change to service directory: file does not exist
fail: nginx: unable to change to service directory: file does not exist
...
```

I'm not yet an expert with neither systemd nor runit, but here is some debug information:

```
# systemctl status private_chef-runsvdir-start.service
● private_chef-runsvdir-start.service - private_chef Runit Process Supervisor
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/private_chef-runsvdir-start.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2015-11-15 14:52:13 UTC; 36min ago
 Main PID: 2572 (runsvdir)
   CGroup: /system.slice/private_chef-runsvdir-start.service
           ├─2572 runsvdir -P /opt/opscode/service log: ....................................................................................................................................................................................
           ├─2702 runsv rabbitmq
           ├─2719 ....
```

Inspecting the status of the `sv` command:

```
# sv status bookshelf
fail: bookshelf: unable to change to service directory: file does not exist

# sv status /opt/opscode/service/bookshelf/
run: /opt/opscode/service/bookshelf/: (pid 6075) 2242s; run: log: (pid 6116) 2241s
```

I assume that at some point `sv` is missing the path parameter that `runsvdir` (`-P /opt/opscode/service`) got supplied. Any way to add this additional directory to the "search path" of `runit`?

EDIT: Exporting `$SVDIR` (`export SVDIR=/opt/opscode/service`) helps me solve the problem at least for the current user session. Issue still is that `sudo` will ignore this, wherever it is exported.